# Swift issues getting images from URL in forEach list

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I'm currently trying to transition from a web developer only to a mobile and web developer and have been having great difficulties learning swift, I think I learn something and write it only to have numerous errors. Right now I have the following code to get an image from my server inside of a foreach loop.

```
struct MainNotLoggedInView: View {

    @ObservedObject var fetcher = Fetcher()

    func getPic(urlLink: String) -> Image? {

        let baseURL = "https://mywebsite.com"

        let url = URL(string: baseURL + urlLink)

        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

        let image = UIImage(data: data!)

        let image2 = Image(uiImage: (image ?? nil)!)

        return image2
    }

    var body: some View{

        VStack{
            TabView {
                ScrollView {
                    ZStack {
                        if fetcher.hasFinished == true {
                        VStack {
                            Text("Featured").font(.largeTitle).padding()
                            ForEach(fetcher.ac?.ac.featuredAc ?? []) { result in
                            VStack {
                                Text(result.name)
                                Image(self.getPic(urlLink: result.acPic))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        } else {
                            Text("Featured").font(.largeTitle).padding()
                        }
                    }
                }.tabItem {
                    Text("Featured").font(.subheadline)
                }
                OtherView().tabItem {
                    Text("Other").font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I assume in order to figure out what is going on, I should also include the JSON fetcher script and the structures, which are below

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation

public struct AcModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    public let id: Int
    public let name: String
    public let acPic: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case acPic = "picture_link"
    }
}

public struct AcModel2: Codable {
    public let location: String
    private var popular: [String:AcModel]
    public var popularAc: [AcModel] {
        get {
            return Array(self.popular.values)
        }
    }
    private var featured: [String:AcModel]
    public var featuredAc: [AcModel] {
        get {
            return Array(self.featured.values)
        }
    }
}

public struct AcModel: Codable {
    public let ac: AcModel2
}

public class Fetcher: ObservableObject {
    public let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Fetcher,Never>()

    @Published var hasFinished: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    var ac: AcModel?

    init(){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/api/loadactivitiesguest") else { return }

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode(AcModel.self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.ac = decodedLists
                        self.hasFinished = true
                        print("dispatching")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I'm sure because I'm a web developer by trade I'm thinking about it the wrong way, but as you can tell from the code, I'm trying to get the picture inside the foreach using the swift method of retrieving pictures from a server, and trying to display it. The code as I have it written has the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". This error is on the line inside the actual view where I try to call the function; "Image(self.getPic(urlLink: **result.acPic**))" 
I bolded the actual words highlight by the error.

Of course, the acPic variable is an actual variable, which is not optional, of the structure. I've seen a lot of other StackOverflow posts about this error, but as with several of the swift errors, it seems the same error message can be caused by several difference types of code with different purposes, and in combination with my lack of swift experience, I have difficulty understanding the relation between what they did wrong and what I did wrong.

From reading around however, I read that I should use something called Kingfisher to cache the images as there is hundreds. How do I install those git repositories into my project? Just a side question, no need to really answer there's probably hundreds of videos.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
Image(self.getPic(urlLink: result.acPic))
```

to

```
self.getPic(urlLink: result.acPic)
```

Image hasn't a init method which gets an optional Image object and returns an Image object